# HTTPS C# Post?

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

I am trying to login to a HTTPS website and then navigate to download a report using c# (its an xml report) ?

I have managed to login OK via cookies/headers etc - but whenever I navigate to the link once logged in, my connection takes me to the "logged out" page ?

Anyone know what would cause this ?

Comment: can you post some code snippets so we can see how you're attempting to do this now?

Comment: when you login are you then passing whatever cookie the server sends back in your subsequent requests?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) you use for your login is the same one you use when downloading the actual report.

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer();
var wr1 = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(url1);
wr1.CookieContainer = cookies;
// do login here with wr1

var wr2 = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(url2);
wr2.CookieContainer = cookies;
// get the report with wr2
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be any number of reasons. Did you pass in the cookie to the download request? Did you pass a referrer URL?

The best way to check is to record a working HTTP request with Wireshark or any number of Firefox extensions or Fiddler.

Then try to recreate the request in C#