# HttpWebRequest Login data Then Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to use HttpwebRequest and Httpwebresponse to log into a website via POST then once authenticated have it redirect to a default page within the new site. I'm able to do a responsereader.ReadttoEnd() put am unsure of how to get an automatic redirect.

```
     Dim ccContainer As New CookieContainer()
            Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding()
            Dim strId As String = "username"
            Dim strName As String = "password"

 Dim postData As String = "UAPMURL=&UAPMURLxx=xx&login=" & strId
        postData += ("&password1=" & strName)
        Dim data As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

        ' Prepare web request...
        Dim myRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.LOGINURLHERE.COM/LOGIN.PHP?"), HttpWebRequest)

        Dim cc As New CookieContainer


        ' <<--- This is the key word of the day
        myRequest.Method = "POST"
        myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = False
        myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        myRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"
        myRequest.KeepAlive = True
        myRequest.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()

        myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length
        Dim newStream As Stream = myRequest.GetRequestStream()
        ' Send the data.
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        newStream.Close()

        Dim _response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(myRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        If myRequest.HaveResponse Then
            For Each retCookie As Cookie In _response.Cookies
                cc.Add(retCookie)
            Next
        End If

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.DESTINATIONURL.COM/Main.php"), HttpWebRequest)
        request.CookieContainer = cc
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = False


        Dim _res As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

---

If I do this ...

Comment out this line

```
 'Dim _res As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

Use these...it reads and fill my current page with the data from the destination URL. Am I missing something to get it to auto redirect? Thanks

```
   Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.destinationurl.com"), HttpWebRequest)
    request.CookieContainer = cc
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = False

 Dim responseReader As New StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Dim responseData As String = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
    responseReader.Close()
    Response.Write(responseData)
```

Comment: answered here:

[StackOverflow: Maintaining state][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036854/httpwebrequest-and-httpwebresponse-maintaining-state-of-logged-in-request-for-c

Comment: I understand that but am not sure how I get it to redirect? Should it automatically redirect?

Comment: Clients (HttpWebRequest) do not redirect.  Servers (IIS/ASP.NET) redirect.  So all you have to do is authenticate, populate the cookiecontainer, then issue a new request to the final target uri and be sure to reuse that cookiecontainer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't redirect; The server redirects.

- If the server sends you a redirect response (code=3xx), you request the URL it redirects you to.
- If the redirect is handled transparently, the `_response.ResponseURI` will contain the address it redirected to.  If not, you have to read the redirect header and decide yourself whether or not to request the new page.
- If the server doesn't redirect at all, you just need to request whatever URL you want once you have your authentication cookie.

Comment: my _repsonse.StatusCode = OK{200} and 

my _repsonse.Headers 

Content-Language: en
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2011 15:51:10 GMT
Expires: Tue, 08 Oct 1996 08:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=abcKXoukfUu528qDi14lt; path=/,Coyote-2-ac1f0273=ac1f022b:0; path=/
Server: Resin/3.1.6

_response.ResponseUri = "http://www.myurl.com/login.php?" same as above, should this be the destination url?

Comment: What is `_response.ResponseURI`  And incidentally why do you set `myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = False` if you *want* to automatically redirect?

Comment: the _repsonse.ResponseURI  "http://www.myurl.com/login.php"
I have changed the AllowAutoRedirect to true before but i'm having the same issue.

Comment: how do i do # 3 request the URL that I want once i get the cookie?

Comment: I did that but it doesn't redirect, it's just fills the page with the new request value. I would like to redirect it. code snippet? thanks

Comment: Does the server just not redirect?  You would have to fix that in server code, not client side code.

Comment: when the responseReader.ReadToEnd() is process it just fills my current page with the data from the DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.destinationurl.com"), HttpWebRequest), does not redirect. Should this redirect?