# Redirect url to obtain the direct url

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, url, redirect

I did an application which parses an html document and then obtains some urls, the problem is the urls only can be downloaded directly from the navigator.

In VB.NET or C#, how I could redirect this url to obtain a direct link for later paste the link to download it in a Download Manager?

```
dim url as string = "http://m.mrtzcmp3.net/get.php?singer=Madonna&song=Like%20A%20Virgin%20&size=5242104&ids=687474703a2h2h63733434303876342g766s2g6f652h75323237363831362h617564696h732h3132323564303466333839622g6f7033"
```

I need to say that I'm not much experimented with http things, maybe I'm wrong and the url has anything to redirect or something similar fault, please just say me how can I redirect that kind of urls or If I'm wrong.

> UPDATE:

Tried this, but I get the same url without any changes:

```
    Dim url As String = _
    "http://m.mrtzcmp3.net/get.php?singer=Madonna&song=Like%20A%20Virgin%20&size=5242104&ids=687474703a2h2h63733434303876342g766s2g6f652h75323237363831362h617564696h732h3132323564303466333839622g6f7033"

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse
    Dim resUri As String
    response = request.GetResponse
    resUri = response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri
    MsgBox(resUri)
```

> UPDATE 2:

In the answer from here [HttpWebRequest Login data Then Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731422/httpwebrequest-login-data-then-redirect)

He says

> If the redirect is handled transparently, the _response.ResponseURI
>   will contain the address it redirected to. If not, you have to read
>   the redirect header and decide yourself whether or not to request the
>   new page.

so...if I need to do thatm, how I can do that?

> UPDATE 3:

`DownloadThemAll` plugin for Firefox can obtain the direct urls... as you can see all the urls finishes with an .mp3 file extension, that's what I need

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "redirecting url to obtain a direct link for later paste the link"?

Comment: @Adam Moszczyński the url is for download an MP3 audio file, I hope that if I could do redirection operations to obtain the "real url" which could ends with the filename, something like this: `http://m.mrtzcmp3.net/blahblahblah/file.mp3` , that is a direct link for me, sorry if I think wrong.

Comment: The url might also point to the http handler which will serve the file by writing it directly into response. It does not have to be "real url" out there.

Comment: the URL/Nombre on DownThenAll is not an url, its merely a filename.

you can get that filename using httpwebresponse.headers (its somewhere in that data) but thats not useful for you. 

i'm pretty sure the urls you gave was the download url

Comment: i'm not entirely sure what you're asking tbh, but the direct url IS the url at the top of your post (the really long thing) and can be downloaded with webclient.downloadfile(url, filename + "mp3")

Comment: @puser I've read your answer but I need to test it about the filename, plase just be patient if it works I mark the answer but I can't touch VS now, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, the url

> http://m.mrtzcmp3.net/get.php?singer=Madonna&song=Like%20A%20Virgin%20&size=5242104&ids=687474703a2h2h63733434303876342g766s2g6f652h75323237363831362h617564696h732h3132323564303466333839622g6f7033

IS the direct url, a direct file url does not need to have the filetype in it.

you can download the file using

```
string url = "http://m.mrtzcmp3.net/get.php?singer=Madonna&song=Like%20A%20Virgin%20&size=5242104&ids=687474703a2h2h63733434303876342g766s2g6f652h75323237363831362h617564696h732h3132323564303466333839622g6f7033"
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
```

you can get the fileName (Madonna-Like A Virgin -www.mrtzcmp3.net.mp3) by using

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
string header =  myHttpWebResponse.Headers.ToString();
fileName = header.Remove(0, header.IndexOf("filename=")+10);
fileName = fileName.Remove(fileName.IndexOf('"'));
```

that is untested, but it should work.

edit: I think this does what you want, but I may have misunderstood your question

Answer (score 1):

Use an `HttpWebRequest` and use the `AllowAutoRedirect=true` to get the direct link and download the file.

Comment: but that not solves my problem, I would to download it outside my application, then I can't use HttpWebRequest to download it either a WebBrowser control, I just would like to obtain the direct link to download it from other application(s). thankyou for answer!

Comment: If you want an external application check my update. Use process.start and give the URL to internet explorer for example.

Comment: I've seen your update but it is the same problem, I still don't have the direct url and I manage big quantities of urls to redirect

Comment: I've tried to do the request but I don't get any changes in the url, please could see my update?

Answer (score 1):

you can perform a web request using web client to get the content (url) from that url, then you just need to perform the redirect.

Comment: thankyou, so you mean I can obtain the redirect url like that?, I'm gonna try it in some minutes

Comment: if you call the url in browser, you can get the url? if yes, you can get it from webclient

Comment: I've tried to do the request but I don't get any changes in the url, please could see my update?

Comment: When I put the url into Firefox the url does not change, it just downloads the file.

Comment: Did you tried to use the webbrowser class? "The WebBrowser control maintains a history list of all the Web pages visited during a browsing session." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url.aspx

Comment: Yes but the `WebBrowser1.Url` property is empty after navigating to the url (before, while, and after downloading the file, the property is empty)... it throws an null reference exception, because `DocumentCompleted` event never is raised when I put the url...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to paste the URL to an URl shortener like tinyUrl or BitLy? Maybe there is a shortener Service that provides an API?

The file then will be downloaded at: http://tinyurl.com/phzhxsr

You will never get a direct URL from the site owner because the URL is dynamicaly parsed and the file is send with the retrun datastream, not by downloading a specific URL.

Comment: Thankyou but I need the direct url, not a shortener, `You will never get a direct URL from the site owner because...` I've updated my question to upload an image to show a program which can obtain the direct urls before downloading them.