# Redirecting after getting HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Hi I'm trying to execute a PHP auto log in API from another domain which accepts the log in details from POST.

I have tested the api using a simple PHP that sends parameters thru post method using the code below and was successfully redirected to the website logged in.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://anotherdomain.com/index.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" value="testuser" hidden><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="passw" value="hashedpassword"><br>
API Login: <input type="text" name="apiuser" value="apiuser"><br>
API PASS: <input type="text" name="apiuser" value="apipass"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Autologin">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to do this on code behind. I have tried the code below but failed to redirect.

```
        string sAPIUser = "apiuser";
        string sAPIPassword = "apipass";
        string sURL = "http://anotherdomain.com/index.php";
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
        string hashPassword = tbPassword.Text.Trim();

        string postData = "user=" + tbUserName.Text.Trim().ToUpper() + "&passw=" + hashPassword + "&apiuser=" + sAPIUser + "&apipass=" + sAPIPassword;

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string sResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        webResponse.Close();

        //when displayed to label displays HTML code from site successfully logged in
        lMessage.Text = sResponse;
```

When I read the sResponse on HTML Visualizer it shows that the user is successfully logged in, but when I add "Response.Redirect(sURL);" it redirects to the site but not logged in. How can I automatically redirect the page after getting the response like the PHP code above. Please help. Thanks. vb.net code is also okay.

Comment: You have to transfer the "access token" that you get from the call to the WebRequest. It is probably a cookie that you have to set using   `Response.Cookies["name_of_cookie"] = "value"`  before you do the redirect. But it's hard to give you a complete answer, not knowing how the authentication works. If you post more information about that, it's probably an easy thing to answer exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML form you have the input field named **APILOGIN** but when you create the postData string in your code you name it **apiuser**

Comment: Oh sorry I just typed the wrong field name, but assuming the field name and parameters are correct is there any correction on the code? on HTML Visualizer it shows that the user is successfully logged in, but what I want to do is redirect the page to the other domain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'll need to use a cookieContainer similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1027594/1552094  I've never used this before so cant really help any more. Hope this gets you on the right track tho